# Sequence of Nested Projections in an arbitrary Normed Linear Space Converges to the Identity

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, alternative-proof, projection

I have seen similar questions on this site, most notably this one: [Convergence of projections onto a nested sequence of subspaces of a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759229/convergence-of-projections-onto-a-nested-sequence-of-subspaces-of-a-hilbert-spac), but they all include the Hilbert space assumption. The following, from Cheney's *Analysis for Applied Mathematics*, is more general:

> Let $P_1, P_2, \cdots$  be a sequence of projections on a normed space
> $X$. Suppose that $P_{n+1} P_n = P_n$ for all $n$ and that the union
> of the ranges of these projections is dense in $X$. Suppose further
> that $\sup_n \|P_n \| < \infty$. Prove that $P_n x \rightarrow x,
> > \forall x \in X.$ [Problem 4.4.3, p.197.]

Thus, $X$ is not even assumed to be a Banach space. These are my thoughts on this:

First, let $V_n$ be the range of each $P_n$. Thus, $X = \overline{ \bigcup _{n=1}^\infty V_n}.$ It is easy to demonstrate that $V_i \subset V_j, j>i:$ $$Let \, \, v_i \in V_i \Rightarrow P_iv_i =v_i.\,\, Then\,\, P_{i+1}(P_i(v_i))=P_iv_i = v_i \Rightarrow v_i \in R(P_{i+1})=V_{i+1}.$$
It is also easy to show that if $x \in V_n \Rightarrow, \exists N,\,s.t.\, P_{N \geq n}x =x.$ Thus, if $x\in \bigcup _{n=1}^\infty V_n \subset X$, then as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\exists N$ such that $P_nx=x, \forall n \geq N.$

But what if $x \in X \setminus \bigcup _{n=1}^\infty V_n $? I understand that in that case, $x$ would be a limit point of the union of the ranges, due to $ \bigcup _{n=1}^\infty V_n$ being dense in $X$.

I cannot push it much further from here though. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions for better approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in X$  and $\epsilon >0$. There exist $y \in \bigcup_n V_n$ such that $\|x-y\| <\epsilon$. Now $\|P_n x-x\| \leq \|P_n x-P_ny\|+\|P_ny-y\|+\|y-x\|\leq (M+1)\epsilon +\|P_n y-y\|$ where $M=\sup_n \|P_n\|$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks so much! So because $y \in \bigcup V_n$, $P_ny-y =0 $ after $n>N$ and the proof follows afterward.